# What is the best way to mock 3rd party library's static method with Mockito in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

The approach I am following now is creating a wrapper around the class providing the static method, and then mocking this wrapper instead of mocking the real class, as in:

```
class TestClass {
  final ThirdPartyClassWrapper _thirdPartyClassWrapper;

  TestClass(this._thirdPartyClassWrapper);

  void someMethod() {
    _thirdPartyClassWrapper.doSomething();
  }
}

class ThirdPartyClass {
  static void doSomething() {}
}

class ThirdPartyClassWrapper {
  void doSomething() {
    ThirdPartyClass.doSomething();
  }
}

//now I can mock the class and control the behaviour of the method
//but there is alot of boilerplate code
class MockThirdPartyClassWrapper extends Mock implements ThirdPartyClassWrapper{}
```

But as you see a lot of boilerplate is introduced.

So is there a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: No, there are no better ways

Comment: Is it worth it then to test these methods or it depends on the case (I am just trying to follow the best practices) @RémiRousselet