# How to Unit Test code that is dependent on 3rd-Party-Package in Flutter?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, flutter-test

How can I test code in flutter, that is dependent on the path_provider plugin?

When executing tests for code that is dependent on the path_provider plugin, I get the following error:

```
  MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getStorageDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
  package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 319:7                         MethodChannel.invokeMethod
  ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
  dart:async                                                                       _asyncErrorWrapperHelper
  package: mypackage someClass.save
  unit_tests/converter_test.dart 19:22   

                                 main.<fn>
```

Comment: did you not mock getStorageDirectory?

Comment: How can I do that? I never worked with mocking before

Comment: use this link: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mock all the methods called by your code being tested if it calls them and depend on their results

in your case you should mock the method `getStorageDirectory()` to make it return some result that satisfy your test

for more info on how to mock check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61158336/9142279)

A short example of how to mock:

```
class MyRepo{
  int myMethod(){
    return 0;
  }
}

class MockRepo extends Mock implements MyRepo{}

void main(){
  MockRepo mockRepo = MockRepo();
  test('should test some behaviour',
          () async {
            // arrange
            when(mockRepo.myMethod()).thenAnswer(1);//in the test when myMethod is called it will return 1 and not 0
            // act
            //here put some method that will invoke myMethod on the MockRepo and not on the real repo
            // assert
            verify(mockRepo.myMethod());//verify that myMethod was called
          },
        );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I created a Mock with Mockito. So how can I make sure that the mock impl is used in the method that should be tested? I'm unit testing a method called convert. This method uses the repository class. I mocked the repository class. But how can I make the convert method use the mock impl?

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it asnwered your question,
and i will edit the answer to show an example of mocking